# Android Manifest.xml Parsing

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new to android system development. I have some experience with android app development though.
I Want to modify the android permissions model and need to provide extra set of permissions in my custom android flavor. 
As an example 
`<uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.My_Permission_Setting" />`
This is intended to be a developer side feature than being a user side feature.

Could anyone help me or point to a resource (other than Android Developers page :)) which gives me where the parsing of the manifest and handling of these permissions takes place..

Thanks in Advance !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect components of your application with your custom permissions. For this you should declare permission in your manifest file `<permission>`. Then in the declaration of your component (activity, service, broadcastreceiver, contentprovider) you should specify this permission in the property (`android:permission="string"`).

If you want to add a permission that will protect a part of Android system then you need to dig into Android system programming. But I do not think that you need such type of permission.

**EDIT:**

You can specify your new permissions in the file `frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml` in Android sources. To check how Android parser works try to look at `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/PackageManagerService.java`

Comment: actually i do such type of permission thanks for help.. As  i said earlier I have just started looking into the android system programming. My current project is to redesign the android permission model and to provide a wrapper around existing permissions and to come up with a new flavor of permissions..!!

Comment: Thanks yury .. Last comment really helps. this is exactly wat i was looking for ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's a full solution but I think that's a direction:

```
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        String permission = "YOUR.CUSTOM.PERMISSION";
        try
        {
            pm.getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        } 
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           // Your permission does not exist...
        }
```

Comment: I am actually looking into what part of the code does the android parses the application manifest file.